# error while running .php from android project

Tags: java, android, json, wampserver

I am trying to connect to mysql db using PHP web service. This is the way I am forming the request

```
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/android_connect/getbrowsedata.php");
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();
      }catch(Exception e){}
              try{
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
            System.out.println("result::"+sb.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
          //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
```

When i run this from a normal java application, I am getting the appropriate result as JSON, which i am able to parse.I am also able to launch it from my browser. When i use this same code in android project,response returns a html with 403 you dont have permission to access .php file on this server (instead of local host i am using my ip address). I have included the user permission in android manifest file. I have also modified the httpd.conf in my WAMP server, changing all the denied to granted as found in the other posts.Is this an issue with any other configuration of the WAMP server.
Any one faced this issue? Any suggestion would be of great help

Comment: Try accessing said url in webbrowser on your device. But I'd check your web server logs and look for errors there

Comment: hey thanks for you suggestion. Any how, i changed "Require local" to Require all granted in httpd.conf and that error went off.